# Netplan generates the same MAC address for bridges on two different machines

Tags: 18.04, netplan

The two machines in question have different MAC addresses for eth0. However, when I apply the following netplan file, I end up with the same MAC address on both machines, which, of course, is kind of a problem. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 on ARM.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
    dhcp4: no

  bridges:
    br0:
    interfaces: [eth0]
    dhcp4: true
```

Comment: MAC addresses, or IP addresses?

Comment: mac addresses. From below, I can work around it by assigning them.

Answer (score 6):

Machines having the same MAC address will mostly only happen when they also have the same machine-id in `/etc/machine-id`. This will be the case if they use a shared systemimage that has that file already.

In that case delete `/etc/machine-id` from the systemimage and reinstall using that image. At first boot the machine will generate a random machine-id and the MAC addresses will be different from other machines.

You can also delete `/etc/machine-id` from an installed machine, but your MAC address and maybe also your ssh server keys will be regenerated.

Comment: Thanks. That's good to know. For know, we assign an address that's based on the IP address. But for my little arm machines I was testing on, this is good info.

Answer (score 5):

**/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      macaddress: 00:1a:3e:c9:20:03
      interfaces: [eth0]
      dhcp4: true
```